# GCP BigQueryOperator table expiration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

How to set table expiration using BigQueryOperator in Airflow when a table is created using query. 
We can update the tables expiration with another BigQueryOperator , but looking for doing the create and setting expiration together.

Comment: Do you want to set an expiration time on the table or on the partitions?

Answer (score 2):

Use a DDL statement in your SQL, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE
  dataset.foo OPTIONS( expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
    description="A table created from SQL with a expiration set" ) AS
SELECT
  'foo' AS col_1
```